# python file returns as No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux

I wrote a python script to query freebase an open source database. I wrote the file in windows and ported it to linux. I have changed the permissions on the file and added the appropriate headers yet the linux shell returns as:

> No such file or directory

Here's the file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import urllib
import string

#query freebase to find results containing graduates from the University of Texas

query1=[{
  "name": null,
  "type": "/people/person",
  "!/education/education/student": [{
    "!/education/educational_institution/students_graduates": [{
      "id": "/en/university_of_texas"
    }]
  }]
}]

query2=[{
  "id": "/en/university_of_texas",
  "/education/educational_institution/students_graduates": [{
    "student": {
      "name": null
    },
        "degree": {
      "name": null
    },
    "end_date": null,
    "major_field_of_study": [{
      "name": null
    }]
  }]
}]

html = urllib.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query="+query2)

library = json.loads(html)

name_dic = {}

for e in library["result"]:

    name_dic[e["student"]["name"]] = [e["degree"]["name"],int(e["end_date"]),e["major_field_of_study"][0]["name"]]

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
c = conn.cursor()
t=[]

for key in name_dic.iterkeys():
    t.append((key, name_dic[key][0],name_dic[key][1],name_dic[key][2]))
try:
    c.executemany('insert into people values(?,?,?,?)',t)
    print "entities found and saved"
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    for k in t:
        try:
            c.execute('insert into people values (?,?,?,?)',k)
            print (str(k[0])+" was added")
        except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
            print "Could not save entities"
conn.commit()
```

Comment: What gives you the 'No such file or directory'?

Comment: Check to see if you actually have /usr/bin/env on your filesystem

Comment: The script has several syntax errors (for example, `null`), so it must be the interpreter.

Comment: You can try replacing `#!/usr/bin/env python` with `#!/usr/bin/python` or try calling the file using `python filename.py` from terminal. I also believe you need to add `import sqlite3`.

Comment: How do you actually run the file? `./freebase.py`, `python freebase.py`, ...?

Answer (score 7):

I came across the same problem recently. The problem was that the file format of the ported file was still in dos format and contained special characters. Running the *dos2unix* on the script file command solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If /usr/bin/env is missing from your Linux system, you will get this error:

```
-bash: ./test.py: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

(where test.py is the name of your script)

If python is missing (which it shouldn't be, most Linux systems depend on it these days), you will get:

```
/usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory
```

There is nothing in the python script itself that I can see that would give you any other error like that, so I suspect it's one of those two.

Answer (score 1):

On shell run following command:

$ which python

Change first line

#! /usr/bin/env python

to

#!_output_of_which_python_

Answer (score -4):

Run it like:

```
python /path/to/file.py
```

Then you can work the rest out later.